# Averaging values within a list of lists

Tags: python

I'm messing around with lists of lists containing strings and values EX: `LofL = [["string", 4.0, 1.1, -3.0, -7.2],["string", 2.0, -1.0, 3.3], ["string", 4.4, 5.5, -6.6, 1.1]]` and I'm trying to take the values within each list within the list, and average them as long as the values are not below 0. For example the first would be 5.1/2 since the third digit is negative. This in the end would make the List of lists look like: `LofL =[["string", 5.1/2],["string", 2/1], ["string", 9.9/2]]`. I've tried this so far:

```
LofL = *see above example*
avgLofL = LofL

for sublist in LofL:
    while sublist in range(1,len(sublist)) > 0.0:
        rowavg = [sum(sublist) / range(1,len(sublist)) for sublist in LofL]
for sublist in avgLofL:
    for sublist in range(1,len(sublist)):
        avgLofL.append(rowavg)

return avgLofL
```

It says my rowavg isn't referenced before assingment, but when I intitialize it as `rowavg = 0` my list has no length. I'm unsure where I'm making a mistake

Comment: Having a nested loop with the same loop variable name overwrites the values. I'd recommend adding `print` statements or using a debugger to see the values of your variables inside the loops.

Comment: Did you forget to declare *avgSales* ?

Comment: Ah i took this from a previous attempt and forgot to rename that

Comment: I'm just trying to take the positive values that appear before any negative ones, for example in the first list of lists that would be 4.0 and 1.1, then calculate the average. The rest of the values after the negative ones do not matter.

Comment: There are several problems with this code, from reusing variables, to trying to divide an integer by a `range()`, to comparing booleans with floats. The only reason this code doesn't throw an error is that the list comprehension will never run.

Comment: Is the first element in each sublist always a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think this is what you actually asked for:

```
LofL = [["string", 4.0, 1.1, -3.0, -7.2],
        ["string", 2.0, -1.0, 3.3],
        ["string", 4.4, 5.5, -6.6, 1.1]]

avgLofL = []
for row in LofL:
    sublist = []
    for x in row[1:]:
      if x>=0:
        sublist.append(x)
      else:
        break
    avgLofL.append([row[0], sum(sublist)/float(len(sublist))])

print(avgLofL)
```

Its result seems to match the example:

> ```
> [['string', 2.55], ['string', 2.0], ['string', 4.95]]
> ```

It processes one `row` at a time, completely. Assumes that the first element is a string which should be kept, then collects the other elements in `sublist` until it finds a negative one. Then calculates the average of the collection, builds and stores a "[string,average]" pair, and continues with the next row.
In its current form it will die on having a negative number right at the start (division by zero). You can either drop an explicit `if` somewhere, or some dirty hack, like `sum(sublist)/max(1,float(len(sublist)))`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a possible solution:

```
from statistics import mean

avgLofL = [[next(x for x in lst if isinstance(x, str)),
            mean(x for x in lst if not isinstance(x, str) and x >= 0)]
           for lst in LofL]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def avgofList(LofL):
    avgLofL = []
    for sublist in LofL:
        total = 0
        count = 0
        for item in sublist:

            if isinstance(item, float) and item > 0:
                total += item
                count += 1

        sl = [x for x in sublist if not isinstance(x, float)]
        sl.append(total / count)
        avgLofL.append(sl)
    return avgLofL
```

Answer (score 0):

Very similar to the answer provided by @tevemadar except that no intermediate lists are used and also accounts for the first negative number being in index 1 of the sub-lists. It does however assume that the sublists are not empty and that the first element is to be retained.

```
LofL = [["string", 4.0, 1.1, -3.0, -7.2],
        ["string", 2.0, -1.0, 3.3],
        ["string", 4.4, 5.5, -6.6, 1.1]]

def process(e):
    t, n = 0, 0
    for v in e[1:]:
        if v >= 0:
            t += v
            n += 1
        else:
            break
    return [e[0], t / n] if n > 0 else [e[0]]

result = [process(e) for e in LofL]

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[['string', 2.55], ['string', 2.0], ['string', 4.95]]
```